# Img is undefine and after restart project i.e `npm start` it not occurs and works fine?

Tags: reactjs, image, runtime-error

[this error sows sometime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN699.jpg)
[Here are error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lohWV.jpg)
[And after restart project i.e `npm start` it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyXxJ.jpg)

I searched for it but could not find it's solution. The syntax looks right and works after restarting the project. ....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.